# Typescript AST Is there a fast way to convert an Expression to their Javascript equivalent?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, typescript-compiler-api

In my Typescript transformer, I am getting the `CallExpression` reference from a function call.

```
function myFunction(param: Record<string, any>){
    
}

const value1 = myFunction({hello: 'hello'});

const params = {hello: 'hello'}
const value2 = myFunction(params);
```

On both of those `myFunction` call expressions, I get an array where I know the first item is the `Expression` of the object I want.

Before I start to parse the Expressions and try to figure out the types manually. Is there a quick way for me to say: "Give me the JavaScript object that is represented by this expression?"

Or Do I always have to do these conversions manually?

I want to get `{hello: 'hello'}` inside the transformer.

Example

```
// Ts code

myFunction({hello: 'hello'});


// Inside some part of the transformer

function convert(callExpression: ts.CallExpression): Record<string, string> {

    const argumentExpression = callExpression.arguments[0];
    // In this place I know `argumentExpression` exist and it is
    // an `ObjectLiteralExpression` or a `Identifier`

    // This should return {hello: 'hello'}
    return someMagicTsFunction(argumentExpression);
}

const converted = convert(myCallExpression); // {hello: 'hello'}

// I can do what I want here with converted :)
```

Comment: Are you using TS compiler?

Comment: @captain-yossarian I am writing a transformer for the typescript compiler, where I get the ASTs (https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/overview/ast)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a hack but it seems to work: get the text of the node, then run that through an `eval()`.

```
let foo: any;
eval('foo = ' + callExpression.arguments[0].getText());
```

`getText()` will fail if the nodes were created programatically because it tries to get the source code, and there is no source code for generated nodes. Depending on your use-case, that may not matter.

If the arguments rely on expressions being evaluated, e.g. `someFunction({a: getBar()})`, then that's obviously not going to work either, because your code won't have `getBar` defined.

If you want something without those 2 limitations then it's going to be much more complicated. It works for the use-case you've given.

Comment: In my first block of code I also used a variable reference. Looks like what I need have to be done manually contemplating each "special" case. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @distante When you start taking into consideration all the possibilities, the problem explodes in complexity. That said, I wrote some simple code for a library I'm working on which kind of inlines local variables. It's [here](https://github.com/michaelboyles/redcr/blob/develop/core/src/remove-locals.ts). In your case, the variable would be removed and the object literal would be moved directly into the argument to the function. You could do something similar in your code

Comment: Thank you for the link! It will help a lot. I am learning the hard way that with Typescript AST one has to do a lot of stuff manually.